# Error al crear conexiones a dos bases de datos en MongoDb en SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Siguiendo un tutorial he creado dos conexiones a bases de datos de MongoDb en SpringBoot que funcionaban perfectamente, pero al cambiar a la versión más reciente del STS (Spring Tool Siute), más concretamente a Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.9.6.RELEASE
Build Id: 201809180749
me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'getMongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not be empty!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbFactorySupport.<init>(MongoDbFactorySupport.java:71) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:69) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:59) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.tutoring.web.mongo.config.AbstractMongoConfig.mongoDbFactory(AbstractMongoConfig.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at org.tutoring.web.mongo.config.PrimaryMongoConnection.getMongoTemplate(PrimaryMongoConnection.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at org.tutoring.web.mongo.config.PrimaryMongoConnection$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9a41f43.CGLIB$getMongoTemplate$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.tutoring.web.mongo.config.PrimaryMongoConnection$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9a41f43$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f5203966.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.tutoring.web.mongo.config.PrimaryMongoConnection$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9a41f43.getMongoTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 56 common frames omitted
```

y no encuentro la solución.
Para crear dos conexiones a BD creo una clase llama AbstractMongoConfig que os detallo:

```
@Data
public abstract class AbstractMongoConfig {

//Mongo DB Properties
  private String host, database;
  private int port;

  /*
   * Method that creates MongoDbFactory
   * Common to both of the MongoDb connections
   */
  public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(getMongoClient(), database);
  }
y dos clases, una para cada BD:
```

1) PrimaryMongoConnection:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"org.tutoring.web.primary.repository"}, mongoTemplateRef = "primaryMongoTemplate")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "primary.mongodb")
public class PrimaryMongoConnection extends AbstractMongoConfig {


@Primary
@Override
@Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
  }
}


  private MongoClient getMongoClient() {
    return new MongoClient(host, port);
  }


  abstract public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate();
```

}
y la otra llamada SecondaryMongoConnection que os detallo también:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
basePackages = {"org.tutoring.web.secondary.repository"},
mongoTemplateRef = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.mongodb")
public class SecondaryMongoConnection extends AbstractMongoConfig {

@Override
public
@Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
  return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
  }
}
```

Estas clases cargan los datos de las BBDD de appication.properties como sigue:

```
primary.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
primary.mongodb.port=27017
primary.mongodb.database=TutoringDb
secondary.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
secondary.mongodb.port=27017
secondary.mongodb.database=tokensDb
```

pero por lo que he podido comprobar depurando no carga los datos que estan en application.properties.
Que estoy haciendo mal?
Falta algo?
Hay algo que se me escapa y no encuentro la solución, y llevo varios días con ello a vueltas, agradecería cualquier ayuda

Comment: Revisa que spring boot estabas usando cuando trabajastes inicialmente porque seguramente con la version 1.5 no tenias problema. En spring boot 2.0 en adelante los parametros de configuracion cambian. Revisa eso....toma tiempo pero generalmente son problemas de configuracion.

Comment: Gracias, revisare la versión de spring boot y los parametros de configuración